# Remover a imagem original do servidor após o Wordpress gerar as thumbnails

Tags: php, wordpress, imagem, php-7, thumbnail

Preciso remover a imagem original que dá origem as thumbnails do Wordpress após as thumbnails serem geradas. Tenho 3 tamanhos de thumbs que utilizo, porém para evitar que o servidor fique com arquivos desnecessários preciso remover a original, que geralmente vem com mais de 4000px de dimensão e com mais de 2.5MB de tamanho. Busquei alguns conteúdos referentes a essa questão porém não encontrei nada. Remover a original após as thumbnails terem sido geradas é possível? E se sim como onde posso encontrar a resposta?

Comment: A melhor forma seria você desativar as thumbnails e utilizar algum plugin como https://wordpress.org/plugins/ewww-image-optimizer/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É possível fazer isso usando o seguinte código:
<sup>(fonte: [How to automatically use resized images instead of originals](http://www.wprecipes.com/how-to-automatically-use-resized-image-instead-of-originals))</sup>

```
add_filter( 'wp_generate_attachment_metadata', 'replace_uploaded_image' );

function replace_uploaded_image($image_data) 
{
    // abortar se não houver versão "large" da imagem
    if ( !isset($image_data['sizes']['large']) ) 
        return $image_data;

    // paths do upload e da imagem grande
    $upload_dir              = wp_upload_dir();
    $uploaded_image_location = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . $image_data['file'];
    $large_image_location    = $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $image_data['sizes']['large']['file'];

    // deletar original
    unlink($uploaded_image_location);

    // renomear a imagem "large"
    rename($large_image_location, $uploaded_image_location);

    // atualizar o metadata da imagem e retornar
    $image_data['width']  = $image_data['sizes']['large']['width'];
    $image_data['height'] = $image_data['sizes']['large']['height'];
    unset($image_data['sizes']['large']);

    return $image_data;
}
```

Também é possível trocar a versão `large` por uma personalizada, como visto em [Auto-modifying original [full size] images](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/54059/12615):

```
add_image_size( 'new-large', 1600, 1200 );
```

E aí, é só trocar todas a ocorrências de `$image_data['sizes']['large']` por `$image_data['sizes']['new-large']`.

Answer (score 0):

Olha... Eu creio que só manualmente. Você pode encontrá-las ou no FTP, na pasta: **wp-content/uploads/** ou na Biblioteca de Mídias.

No entanto, não vejo necessidade para remover as imagens. A grande maioria dos hosts geralmente possuem mais de 5GB de espaço, o que é bem difícil de "lotar". :)

Comment: Se o site também faz uploads de vídeos ou outros arquivos grandes, vai ser bem fácil lotar ;)